# Discrete logarithms and primitive elements in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, computational-number-theory, cryptography, primitive-elements

The recent papers:

- R. Granger, T. Kleinjung, J. Zumbragel, "On the Discrete Logarithm
  Problem in Finite Fields of Fixed Characteristic," Trans. Amer. Math.
  Soc., 370(5) (2018), 3129–3145.
- T. Kleinjung, B. Wesolowski, “Discrete Logarithms in Quasi-polynomial
  Time in Finite Fields of Fixed Characteristic," J. Amer. Math. Soc.,
  35(2) (2022), 581–624.

have established that the discrete logarithm problem can be solved in expected quasi-polynomial time, $e^{{\mathcal O}(\log^2 n)}$, in families of fields $GF(p^n)$ with fixed characteristic $p$. (More generally, the complexity is quasi-polynomial also in the case when $p$ grows polynomially with $n$, if I understood correctly.)

My question is the following: can this algorithm, or a modification thereof, be used for testing whether a given element $g$ is primitive? Namely, if we ask for the logarithm of $h=1$ with respect to base $g$, is it possible to modify the algorithm so that it returns *the smallest positive* integer $x$ satisfying $g^x=1$ (i.e., the order of $g$), instead of *some* integer $x$ that satisfies this relation? Together with a result of V. Shoup:

- V. Shoup,"Searching for Primitive Roots in Finite Fields," Math.
  Comp., 58(197) (1992), 369–380.

this would give a quasi-polynomial time algorithm for finding primitive elements in these families of fields.

P.S. The mathematics in the two above-mentioned papers is beyond my familiarity with the subject, so I was hoping for a direct and simple answer.

Comment: Since $p^n-1$ is a multiple of $x$, finding $x$ is easy if we can factor $p^n-1$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Sure, but we don't know how to do that efficiently as far as I know.

Comment: These are instances of [Cunningham numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_number) and at very least we have [cyclotomic factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). Also, proving that $g$ is *not* primitive in some cases can be done from an incomplete factorization (by noticing that $g^{(p^n-1)/q}=1$ for a known prime divisor $q$).

Answer (score -1):

Ming-Deh Huang and Anand Kumar Narayanan, Finding primitive elements in finite fields of small characteristic, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1206v4.pdf

From the abstract:

We describe a deterministic algorithm for finding a generating element of the multiplicative group of the finite field with $p^n$ elements. In time polynomial in $p$ and $n,$ the algorithm either outputs an element that
is provably a generator or declares that it has failed in finding one. [...] The algorithm relies on a relation generation technique in a recent breakthrough for discrete logarithm computation in small characteristic finite fields.

Followup work includes (included since it was peer reviewed) a paper co-authored by one of the authors above "Generating sets for the multiplicative groups of algebras over finite fields and expander graphs" in the Journal of Symbolic Computation
[available here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771711730072X).